# How to handle Touch in Cocos2Dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

My problem is when is touch at any location of screen the sprite becomes invisible. But i want to do that the sprite should be invisible only when i tap on the sprite.

```
bool CharacterSelection::ccTouchBegan(CCTouch* pTouch, CCEvent* pEvent
{

    CCTouch* touch;
    CCPoint tap =  CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(pTouch->getLocationInView());
    GoatSprite* goat;
    goat = (GoatSprite*) goatSpriteObject;
    if(touch){
        tap = touch->getLocation();    
    }
    if(goat->boundingBox().containsPoint(tap)){
        goat->setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

sorry if there is any mistake in code.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like your code is weird.

1. you are missing a parenthesis after `CCEvent* pEvent`
2. you already have a touch coming in as `pTouch` no need to create a new `CCTouch* touch;`
3. you are using `if (touch)` when you have done nothing with it, that would be `pTouch`
4. you don't even need the `if (touch)` conditional at all.

Try simplifying to:

```
cocos2d::CCPoint p = pTouch->getLocation();
cocos2d::CCRect rect = goat->getBoundingBox();

if(rect.containsPoint(p))
{
     // you touched it              
}
```